# Vagrant - allocating IPs to boxes from an array

Tags: arrays, networking, vagrantfile

I am a total noob in Ruby programming, and even though I (hope I) understood the idea of an anonymous code block, I can't say I understand where I'm failing in the following:

```
MACHINE_MASTER_IP = ENV['MACHINE_MASTER_IP'] || '10.0.3.10'
MACHINE_IPS = ENV['MACHINES_IPS'] || "#{MACHINE_MASTER_IP},10.0.3.20"

$MACHINE_IPS = MACHINE_IPS.split(',')

Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|

$i = 0
while $i < $MACHINE_IPS.length

    $MACHINE_IP = $MACHINE_IPS[$i]
    $MACHINE_NAME="worker_#$1"

    config.vm.define $MACHINE_NAME do |box|

    # --provider virtualbox 
    box.vm.provider :virtualbox do |virtualbox, override|
        override.vm.network "private_network", ip: "#$MACHINE_IP"
        # virtualbox.memory = 2048
        # virtualbox.cpus = 1
        override.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64" # 14.04
        # override.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64" # 14.04
    end

    # config.vm.define
    end

    $i += 1

# while $i < $MACHINE_IPS.length
end

end
```

What I am trying to do, is dynamically generate and run a set of machines, on which I want to apply a set of ips given from the command line. Smth like:

```
MACHINE_IPS="192.168.0.1,192.168.0.2,192.168.0.3" vagrant up
```

The problem in my code above is that each machine I create (yes, it create all 3 of them) will be set with the last ip (192.168.0.3).

To be honest, I don't really know what to try anymore, so I'm calling for your help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Seems I must be answering for myself. Found the answer a few days after I asked..

In stead of using while, I used the `1..n`.each block code syntax.

```
MACHINE_MASTER_IP = ENV['MACHINE_MASTER_IP'] || '10.0.3.10'
MACHINE_IPS = ENV['MACHINES_IPS'] || "#{MACHINE_MASTER_IP},10.0.3.20"

$MACHINE_IPS = MACHINE_IPS.split(',')

Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|

(1..$MACHINE_IPS.length).each do |i|

    $MACHINE_IP = $MACHINE_IPS[$i]
    $MACHINE_NAME="worker_#$1"

    config.vm.define $MACHINE_NAME do |box|

    # --provider virtualbox 
    box.vm.provider :virtualbox do |virtualbox, override|
        override.vm.network "private_network", ip: "#$MACHINE_IP"
        # virtualbox.memory = 2048
        # virtualbox.cpus = 1
        override.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64" # 14.04
        # override.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64" # 14.04
    end

    # config.vm.define
    end

    $i += 1

# while $i < $MACHINE_IPS.length
end

end
```

With a few more tweaks everything worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Vagratfile follows ruby syntax and below works for me just fine

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

users = ["puser", "guser", "kuser"]
uid_start = 10000
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.define "machinea" do |machinea|
    machinea.vm.box = "ubuntu/bionic64"
    machinea.vm.box_version = "20200618.0.0"
    machinea.vm.box_check_update = false
    machinea.vm.boot_timeout = 300
    machinea.vm.hostname = "machinea"
    machinea.vm.network "public_network", bridge: "en0: Wi-Fi (AirPort)", auto_config: false
    machinea.vm.provision "shell", run: "always", inline: "ifconfig enp0s8 192.168.0.17 netmask 255.255.255.0 up"
    machinea.ssh.insert_key = false
    machinea.ssh.private_key_path = ['~/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key', '/myworks/vagrant/.ssh/vagrant_rsa']
    machinea.vm.provision "file", source: "/myworks/vagrant/.ssh/vagrant_rsa.pub", destination: "~/.ssh/authorized_keys"
    machinea.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-EOC
      sudo sed -i -e "\\#PasswordAuthentication yes# s#PasswordAuthentication yes#PasswordAuthentication no#g" /etc/ssh/sshd_config
      sudo systemctl restart sshd.service
      echo "finished"
    EOC
    users.each do |user|
        uid_start += 1
        machinea.vm.provision "shell", run: "once", privileged: true, inline: <<-CREATEUSER
        sudo useradd -m -s /bin/bash -U #{user} -u #{uid_start}
        sudo mkdir /home/#{user}/.ssh
        sudo cp /vagrant/.ssh/#{user}_rsa.pub /home/#{user}/.ssh/authorized_keys
        sudo chown -R #{user}:#{user} /home/#{user}
        sudo su
        echo "%#{user} ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" > /etc/sudoers.d/#{user}
        exit
      CREATEUSER
    end
  end
end
```